# Conditional Mapping in Entity Framework - OR operation with TPH

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, tph

We have an entity like `Vehicle` and three derived entities such as `Car`, `Motorbike` and `Bicycle`.
This inheritance hierarchy is implemented with **TPH**.

Here are entity mapping conditions:

- `__disc__ = car` for Car
- `__disc__ = motorbike` for Motorbike
- `__disc__ = bicycle` for Bicycle

  ***How can I*** derive another child from `Vehicle` like `MotorVehicle` with following mapping condition:
- `__disc__ = car OR motorbike` for MotorVehicle

I'd view in Database like this when I had this structure with **TPT**:

```
SELECT    Id
FROM      Vehicles
WHERE     (__Disc__ = N'car') OR (__Disc__ = N'motorbike')
```

I think this view is not required with TPH.

***Please note that*** I can not change the inheritance like this: Vehicle<-- MotorVehicle<-- Car. Don't think about injecting the motor vehicles as the parent of car and other children because Car and Motorbike and Bicycle are already exists. I just want to assign some business to all motor vehicles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why couldn't you introduce a `MotorVehicle` level in the class hierarchy? You can. It's just an abstract class, so it doesn't need a discriminator value. EF hardly notices the class!

I tried both with and without the `MotorVehicle` class and the database structure and the number of defined discriminators was the same in both cases.

---

**Edit**

This is what I did:

```
public abstract class Vehicle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class MotorVehicle : Vehicle
{
    public int Hp { get; set; }
}

public class Car : MotorVehicle
{ }

public class MotorBike : MotorVehicle
{ }

public class Bicycle : Vehicle
{ }

internal class NestedInheritanceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().Property(v => v.Name).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Car>().Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator")
            .HasValue("car").HasColumnType("char")
            .HasMaxLength(10)
            .IsRequired());
        modelBuilder.Entity<MotorBike>().Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator")
            .HasValue("motorbike"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<Bicycle>().Map(m => m.Requires("Discriminator")
            .HasValue("bicycle"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean I implement MotorVehicle not in DAL, right?
Then, there is no motor vehicle in DAL but it's a business related thing, right?

Comment: would you please give me more details and provide the model? I can not create an abstract entity.